# Smart Broker vs. Dumb Broker (Kafka and RabbitMQ)

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-kafka

In discussing the differences between Kafka and RabbitMQ, "dumb broker" and "smart broker" keeps popping up in their interactions with consumers.  Kafka is described as having a dumb broker while RabbitMQ is said to have a smart broker/dumb consumer model.

What exactly does this mean?  I'm familiar with the basics of Kafka and a little bit more about RabbitMQ.  However, what features of RabbitMQ makes the broker smarter than Kafka's?

Answer (score 16):

This is a question that bothered me for sometime too :) Here's what I have understood so far...

In the case of RabbitMQ the broker makes sure the messages are delivered to the consumers and dequeue them only when it gets acknowledgement from all the consumers that need that message. It also keeps track of consumer state.

Kafka does not keep track of "which messages were read by consumers". The Kafka broker keeps all messages in queues for a fixed duration of time and it's the responsibility of the consumer to read it from the queue. It also does not have this overhead operation of keeping track of consumer state.

You can read more about it in this awesome [Pivotal blog](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/understanding-when-to-use-rabbitmq-or-apache-kafka) post comparing RabbitMQ and Kafka.

Comment: This is false. Kafka does indeed track consumer state. It tracks offsets, though, and does not inspect message content for tracking purposes. Also, the "fixed duration" can be disabled.

Answer (score 5):

The point about Kafka using a dumb broker while Rabbit MQ using a smart broker is one of the points used while deciding which Messaging System to use. Since RabbitMQ is a smart broker implementing global startegies for retry is far easier and listener agnostic than in Kafka.

Given a set of microservices accessed through an API gateway I believe that the above point, combined with the advantages of Rabbit MQ being much more maintainable and the knowledge that the data passed across microservices will never amount to the same load as that of streaming data, makes Rabbit MQ a far better choice than Kafka for Inter Service Communication

Comment: How exactly is "retry easier"? Are you referring to producers or consumers?

Answer (score 3):

Dumb vs Smart broker means that the Broker can be smart to route messages based on certain conditions.

**In the case of RabbitMQ,** producer sends message to Exchange and Exchange routes the message to Queue. Here "Exchange" does the routing and thats what they call as Smart broker. Again people have made Brokers really smart and ended up with ESB which we all know what happened and Industry is moving away from Bloated ESB's.

**In the case of Kafka,** broker doesn't route messages. It is up to the user to create topics, producers partition the events into topic-partitions, and consumer groups and decide which consumer groups listens to which topic.

Smart vs Dumb broker has nothing to do with Message acknowledgment. In case of RabbitMQ, it tracks the status of each message to see whether it is consumer or not. In the case of Kafka, it happens but differently by using offsets on partitions and offset is stored in Kafka itself ( consumer can also store). But both provide the functionality.